# Comparign __exact and get()

Tags: django, django-models

What is the need of __exact query lookup if we can simply fetch data using get().

I mean what are the extra benefits of __exact in querysets ??

Comment: They're completely different things, get retrieves a *single instance* and `__exact` is part of a query, it does not dictate that it can only apply for a single instance

Answer (score 0):

.get() is used to get a single instance. We use get when sure of single objects being returned by the queryset.
If multiple instances are present it will throw you an error on console:

```
get() returned more than one person -- it returned 2!
```

A typical get query for a Person model would be:

```
Person.objects.get(id=1)
```

However, `__exact` is used with a queryset as a parameter check. For example:
if we have a model `Person`, and you want to find all the person objects whose names are exactly = "Luv33preet".

Queryset for this would be:

```
Person.objects.filter(name__exact="Luv33preet")
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both are not comparable both have different uses

models.py -

```
class Model1.py():
    name= models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
```

views.py(Query) -

```
  Model1.objects.get(name='RakeshRao') #retrieve single object
  Model1.objects.get(name__exact='RakeshRao') #part of query same as 'LIKE' in SQL
```